# Root property of a nested JSON or model in sencha

Tags: json, extjs, model, store

i have a json in the following format:

```
{
 "collection": [
 {
  "id": 4, 
  "tickets": {
    "collection": [
      {
        "inner_id": 8,
      },
      {
        "inner_id": 10,
      }
    ],
    "count": 2,
    "type": "collection"
   },
  },
  {
  "id": 5, 
  "tickets": {
    "collection": [
      {
        "inner_id": 1,
      },
      {
        "inner_id": 2,
      }
    ],
    "count": 2,
    "type": "collection"
   },
  },
 ]
}
```

For this particular JSON i created the models as:

```
Ext.define("myProject.model.ABC", {
extend: "Ext.data.Model",
config: {
    idProperty: "id",
    fields:[
        {name: "id", type: "int" },
    ],
    hasMany: [
        {
            model: "myProject.model.XYZ",
            name: "tickets",
            associationKey: "tickets",
        },
    ],
  }
});
```

And second store as:

```
Ext.define("myProject.model.XYZ", {
extend: "Ext.data.Model",
config: {
    // idProperty: "id",
    fields:[
     {name: "inner_id", type: "int" },

    ],
     belongsTo: 'myProject.model.ABC'
 }
});
```

But now i am confused. How do i populate the second store with a root property of collection again.

I know one way is to easily change the json so that there is no collection child inside tickets but i dont want to do that.

Any help would be appreciated. I have simplified the JSON for an easy example.

EDIT:
To be more clear, is there a way i can directly create a model which will read the Collection array inside the tickets object.

EDIT: 
Adding the store which populates the model ABC for more understanding

```
Ext.define("myProject.store.ABCs", {
extend: "Ext.data.Store",
config: {
    model: "myProject.model.ABC",
    autoLoad: false,            
    proxy: {
        type: "ajax",
        url: '',  //myURL
        reader: {
            type: "json",
            rootProperty: "collection",   // this is the first collection
        },
    },

 }
});
```

This store loads the ABC model correctly but now i want to load the XYZ model which can load the inner array of collection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to solve this problem. After researching extensively, i found two solutions...

SOLUTION 1: 
Instead of making a second model, just create one model and create an array field with type as "auto"

```
Ext.define("myProject.model.ABC", {
extend: "Ext.data.Model",
config: {
 idProperty: "id",
 fields:[
    {name: "id", type: "int" },
    { name: "tickets", convert: function(value, record) {
            if(value.collection instanceof  Array) {
                return value.collection;
            } else {
                 return [value.collection]; // Convert to an Array 
            }
              return value.collection;
        }
    }
 ],
 }
});
```

Now you can refer to an array of tickets from records by:

```
 record.get('tickets')
```

SOLUTION 2: 
Create three model instead of two.

Model 1: 
     hasOne Association with Tickets

Model 2:
     hasMany association with Collection

Model 3: 
     has all the fields of the innermost array

I can give an example if its not clear enough

Comment: Mehul, if you don't mind could you please share secod method code with us?

Answer (score 2):

`belongsTo` should be define as follows :

```
Ext.define('Product', {
extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
fields: [
    { name: 'id',          type: 'int' },
    { name: 'category_id', type: 'int' },
    { name: 'name',        type: 'string' }
],
associations: [
    { type: 'belongsTo', model: 'Category' }
]
```

Have you read the doc? They specified the `root` property.

> The name of the property which contains the data items corresponding to the Model(s) for which this Reader is configured. For JSON reader it's a property name (*or a dot-separated list of property names if the root is nested*). For XML reader it's a CSS selector. For Array reader the root is not applicable since the data is assumed to be a single-level array of arrays.
>
> By default the natural root of the data will be used: the root JSON array, the root XML element, or the array.
>
> The data packet value for this property should be an empty array to clear the data or show no data.
>
> Sometimes the JSON structure is even more complicated. Document databases like CouchDB often provide metadata around each record inside a nested structure like this:

```
{
    "total": 122,
    "offset": 0,
    "users": [
        {
            "id": "ed-spencer-1",
            "value": 1,
            "user": {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "Ed Spencer",
                "email": "ed@sencha.com"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

> In the case above the record data is nested an additional level inside the "users" array as each "user" item has additional metadata surrounding it ('id' and 'value' in this case). To parse data out of each "user" item in the JSON above we need to specify the record configuration like this:

```
reader: {
    type  : 'json',
    root  : 'users',
    record: 'user'
}
```

**`root` as a Function**

```
reader: {
    type  : 'json',
    root  : function (obj) {
            // I can't reproduce your problem
            // so you should check in your console collection.id is right
            return obj.collection.id
        }
}

// Or, we can use dot notation

reader: {
    type  : 'json',
    root  : collection[0].tickets.collection
}
```

Comment: I have tested belongsTo and it works fine. And my question isnt about how to write belongsTo. Its about how to define the root property for the second inner model

Comment: I see, you just edited your answer. Now the problem is that in your JSON, the users is an array but in my case, i have it as:   users:{ collection:[ ] }     .. Now i want to make my inner model populate the array of collection. How do i do that?

Comment: Dear Mehul, you can specify the `root` as a function, check answer.

Comment: I have editted the question to explain more. I know the root can be used as a function. But the reader will be defined in the store. How do i define the reader in the model and populate the array of inner collection. Could you expand your answer by designing the model for the JSON in the question?

Comment: You can't define reader in the model ( to be honest I don't know which I didn't see any example )

Comment: Well thats the problem, hence why i posted the question on stack overflow :)

Comment: There is one way but I don't know have you used proxy. You can define a proxy parameter over model than specify the `reader` property on the proxy defition.

Comment: Yes i tried that. But if i use that, will XYZ model be hasOne relationship or hasMany relationship? because tickets is an object and not an array.

Comment: FYI, "root" has been renamed "rootProperty" in ExtJS 5.